# Getting the byte bits as string

Tags: c#, .net, string

I want to the bits (0 or one) from a byte in a string but I don't know how?
                  Thanks.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I bet there's a cleverer way to do this, but it works:

```
private string byteToBitsString(byte byteIn)
{
    char[] bits = new char[8];
    bits[0] = Convert.ToString((byteIn / 128) % 2);
    bits[1] = Convert.ToString((byteIn / 64) % 2);
    bits[2] = Convert.ToString((byteIn / 32) % 2);
    bits[3] = Convert.ToString((byteIn / 16) % 2);
    bits[4] = Convert.ToString((byteIn / 8) % 2);
    bits[5] = Convert.ToString((byteIn / 4) % 2);
    bits[6] = Convert.ToString((byteIn / 2) % 2);
    bits[7] = Convert.ToString((byteIn / 1) % 2);
    return bits;
}
```

Comment: See the other answer using Convert.ToString(value,2).PadLeft(8,'0') instead.

Comment: This answer is actually almost working, it had the wrong braces in the code, as it was converted from VB and the author probably did not have much experience in C# to spot the error. I fixed it. Obviously, this answer is quoted here and the quote gets positive score, it is IMHO reasonable to give a chance to the original answer to shine as well.

Answer (score 37):

Take a look at [Convert.ToString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.tostring.aspx). You can use it both ways, for the conversion byte->bit-string and vice versa.

```
byte value = 56;
// There ...
string bits = Convert.ToString(value, 2);
// ...and Back Again
value = Convert.ToByte(bits, 2);
```

Comment: This answer should be the accepted answer.  When given only a single argument, Convert.ToString(byte) returns a hex string, but when given the second argument, Convert.ToString(byte,int) can use base 2, 8, 10, or 16.  ```Convert.ToString(56,2)``` returns ```"111000"``` but if you want *all* the bits, then ```Convert.ToString(56,2).PadLeft(8,'0')``` returns ```"00111000"```

Answer (score 4):

Here's clweek's re-written method, that actually works: 
I have used StringBuilder class instead of char array. 
Sample: `byteToBitsString(157)` prints "00101111"

```
private string byteToBitsString(byte byteIn)
    {
        var bitsString = new StringBuilder(8);

        bitsString.Append(Convert.ToString((byteIn / 128) % 2));
        bitsString.Append(Convert.ToString((byteIn / 64) % 2));
        bitsString.Append(Convert.ToString((byteIn / 32) % 2));
        bitsString.Append(Convert.ToString((byteIn / 16) % 2));
        bitsString.Append(Convert.ToString((byteIn / 8) % 2));
        bitsString.Append(Convert.ToString((byteIn / 4) % 2));
        bitsString.Append(Convert.ToString((byteIn / 2) % 2));
        bitsString.Append(Convert.ToString((byteIn / 1) % 2));

        return bitsString.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Was mine bugged?  I converted it from VB and don't use C# regularly, so there's room for dumb error, but what is it?

Answer (score 2):

Or the deluxe variant of the bit banging way to do it:

```
    public static string ToByteFormat(int valIn, int digits)
    {
        var bitsString = new StringBuilder(digits);
        int mask = (1 << digits - 1);
        for(int i = 0; i < digits; i++)
        {
            bitsString.Append((valIn & mask) != 0 ? "1" : "0");
            mask >>= 1;
        }
        return bitsString.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one bit banging way to do it:

```
public static string ByteToBinaryString(byte byteIn)
{
    StringBuilder out_string = new StringBuilder();
    byte mask = 128;
    for (int i = 7; i >=0 ; --i)
    {
        out_string.Append((byteIn & mask) != 0 ? "1" : "0");
        mask >>= 1;
    }
    return out_string.ToString();
}
```